# What does exclamation point mean here

Tags: perl, filehandle

What does the exclamation point mean in the this example? The one right before 'open'? The book can't answer my question..

```
if ( ! open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd") {
    die "How did you get logged in? ($!)";
}

while (<PASSWD>) {
    chomp;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know what "the book" is, but it is documented in [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Symbolic-Unary-Operators).

Comment: Bareword filehandles and the two-argument form of `open` make me suspect that "the book" is quite outdated. (Opening `/etc/passwd` directly instead of using `getpwent` and friends is suspicious too, but those *are* obscure functions...)

Comment: Modern idiomatic usage would be  something like `open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd" or die "How did you get logged in? ($!)\n";`

Comment: Would be more readable to newbies: `if ( not open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd")`. However, I agree with Shawns comment on idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is the boolean negation operator.

- Given a true value, it returns false.
- Given a false value, it returns true.

`open(...)` returns false on error and true on success.

Therefore, `!open(...)` returns true on error and false on success.

The `if`'s block is executed if the expression (`!open(...)`) is true.

Therefore, the `if`'s block is executed if `open` returned an error.

Perl's symbolic operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).